# How can I implement basic authentication between Next.JS and DRF using JWT?

Tags: django, authentication, next.js, jwt

I am trying to recode the website for my student club and would need some assistance regarding authentication.
I do have a Django Backend setup with all the necessary data (e.g. Member infos, etc.) and would like to display them on the frontend (name + position) and on the Backend (email, phone number, etc.). Now to achieve that I would need basic authentication where I can give out login credentials to the members and they can login (no sign up from the website).
Now I am wondering how to do that; coming from Django I would generate a credential pair and the authentication would go via JWT, but I cant find a suitable example (everything is very old).
Right now my setup looks like this:

- Django Backend with JWT
- Next.JS frontend (typescript, tailwind css) with seperate login page

I was looking at next-auth which seems promising but I am afraid that login via Socials is not my usecase.
Can anyone provide more information how to setup Django with Next.JS with authentication?
Cheers

I already tried using Next-Auth with some examples provided on the internet but none of them worked/ were deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), easy plug-and-play JWT-based auth.